# .NET Dropbox API download large file in chunks

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox-api

I need to download large files from Dropbox with size more than 100GB each. I'm using Dropbox .NET API for that.

To do that kind-like in chunks I call `GetContentAsStream` method as below:

```
var response = await client.Files.DownloadAsync(filePath);
using (var stream = await response.GetContentAsStreamAsync())
{
    var length = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize, token);

    // Append to local file.
}
```

After 5GB or so I get error: `Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.`

Is there any explicit way to download chunk of a Dropbox file specifying offset and number of bytes? That way I will be able to retry or continue from the position I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API v2 [/2/files/download](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download) HTTPS endpoint itself does support "Range Retrieval Requests", but that's unfortunately not currently implemented in the Dropbox .NET SDK. I'll send this along as a feature request for that, but I can't promise if/when that would be implemented there.

That being the case, you could implement the HTTPS call directly, outside of the SDK, so you can set the desired `Range` header.

Comment: I played with the download API with Postman. The range retrieval request seems to work just fine. Will rewrite my code. Thanks!